# Counterexample to uniformly continuous extension theorem when A is not dense in X

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

We have that if $X$ is a metric space, $Y$ is a complete metric space, $A\subseteq X$ is dense in $X$ and $f:A \to Y$ is uniformly continuous then there exists a (unique) uniformly continuous extension of $f$ to $X$. This has been asked here many times, my question regards a variation of this result.

Does this still hold if $A$ is not necessarily dense in $X$? That is, for every $A\subseteq X$ and every uniformly continuous $f:A\to Y $ there exists at least one uniformly continuous extension to $X$.

I believe this is not true, and I think I've been able to find a counterexample, but it's much more complicated than what would seem necessary given the question, and I'd like to know if there's some obvious counterexample that I may have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, consider $X$ to be any connected space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$), pick two distinct points $x,y\in X$ and let $A=Y=\{x,y\}$. Of course a finite metric space is trivially complete.

With that we have a very simple counterexample. Let $f:A\to Y$ be $f(x)=x$. Clearly it cannot be extended to full $X$, even in continuous way, because $X$ is connected while $Y$ is not.

---

Note that if $Y=\mathbb{R}^n$ (and even more generally I think it holds for any ANR), and $f:A\to Y$ is uniformly continuous and bounded, then $f$ can be extended to uniformly continuous and still bounded $\overline{f}:\overline{A}\to Y$, and then it can be extended to full $X$ (in uniformly continuous way), as a variant of Tietze extension theorem.

I don't know whether "bounded" condition can be dropped. Obviously $Y$ cannot be replaced with arbitrary complete space.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! As a side note, I believe the boundedness condition is necessary, consider $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(n)=e^n$ then if $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where a uniformly continuous extension of $f$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq 1$ if $|x-y|<\delta$ and then taking $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/N < \delta $ we have $e^{n+1} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N} |g(n+i/N)-g(n+(i-1)/N)|+e^n \leq N + e^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ which cannot be because it implies $ e- N/e^n \leq 1$. This was my unnecessarily complicated example!